# BlackBerry GPS Issue with LocationListener - Cellsite untill GPS Locks

Tags: blackberry, gps, locationlistener

I am doing a BlackBerry app targeted at 5.0 and upwards. I have a class that extends Thread and implements LocationListener.

I manage to get gps updates on CellSite as well as the other modes like Assisted and Unassisted.

What I am really trying todo is use Cellsite while the others are not available and then switch to them once they become available.

The correct route seemed through "providerStateChanged" but this never fires.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [BlackBerryLocationProvider](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/gps/BlackBerryLocationProvider.html) and [BlackBerryCriteria](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/gps/BlackBerryCriteria.html) you can specify GPS locations and then enable geolocation with GPS. The system will then provide a geolocation based fix (Cellsite or Wi-Fi) if GPS is not available. This is available starting with OS 5.0.  See the linked API documentation.