# check gps, cell tower and wifi availability

Tags: blackberry, gps, location

I am acquiring the current location in my BlackBerry app through GPS and it is working fine. This location is being updated every few seconds. I would like to introduce a logic to check the availability of GPS, wifi and cell tower and based on that start tracking the location. If for instance, it starts to get location from cell tower and suddenly GPS is now available, I want it to switch to GPS to get coordinates and so on. How should I determine which is available. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gps module checking -

```
 int m_bbHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_lbs");
 if(m_bbHandle<=0){
 //GPS Available
  }
```

For WIFI availability -

```
  if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)&& RadioInfo.areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN)) {
  //WiFi is available
    }
```

For Cell tower -

```
Integer.toString(GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getCellId( ));
//Retrieves the current cell ID.

Integer.toString(GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getLAC());
//Retrieves the Location Area Code.

Integer.toString(GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getBSIC()) ;
//Base Station Identity Code
```

Comment: Thanks Signare. It took me sometime to try out the code in my application. Has helped alot.

Comment: welcome @Sarah. if you need more help come to blackberry chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-iphone-and-java

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting BBOS 5.0 or higher this functionality is baked in. See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535640/blackberry-gps-issue-with-locationlistener-cellsite-untill-gps-locks). If not then the [LocationListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/location/LocationListener.html#providerStateChanged%28javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider,%20int%29) will tell you when GPS service is not available. However pre 5.0 you are unlikely to find devices that have GPS and Cellsite geolocation, so you would have to use techniques like Signare suggests.